# Jasmine tests timeouts after finishing all tests -

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am facing very peculiar issue for Jasmine-Karma for our Angular project.

Our Angular codebase is large and number of UI Jasmine tests has reached 3600+.

We have increased the memory for node as well; we use below command to execute:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --watch=false --code-coverage
```

We use `karma-parallel` package to parallelly execute the tests.

Due to the number of tests (or any other reason), when we execute all our tests, they all get executed, but the Karma (or Jasmine) doesn't send tests completed signal to CI and the CI gets stuck over there. Below is the logs we get - so it waits for the timeout and then it gets disconnected.

Earlier also we faced this issue; by increasing browser instances for karma-parallel library from 3 to 6, increasing browser capture timeout and having `flags: ['--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox']` for the browser, it got resolved. However, this time the issue has started occurring more frequently.

```
Chrome Headless 111.0.5563.111 (Windows 10): Executed 790 of 0 (skipped 2) SUCCESS (1 min 7.852 secs / 26.015 secs)
24 03 2023 00:54:18.347:WARN [Chrome Headless 111.0.5563.111 (Windows 10)]: Disconnected (0 times) reconnect failed before timeout of 180000ms (ping timeout)
Chrome Headless 111.0.5563.111 (Windows 10) ERROR
  Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of 180000ms (ping timeout)
Chrome Headless 111.0.5563.111 (Windows 10): Executed 528 of 0 DISCONNECTED (4 mins 8.438 secs / 14.81 secs)
24 03 2023 00:54:18.357:INFO [karma-server]: Restarting Chrome Headless 111.0.5563.111 (Windows 10) (1 of 2 attempts)
24 03 2023 00:54:19.543:INFO [Chrome Headless 111.0.5563.111 (Windows 10)]: Disconnected browser returned on socket ddVChBkukiwm6yErAAAZ with id 51823139.
24 03 2023 01:44:19.752:WARN [Chrome Headless 111.0.5563.111 (Windows 10)]: Disconnected (1 times) , because no message in 3000000 ms.
```

When we try to execute tests with --max_old_space_size=12288, we get below error on local

```
............................................................
<--- Last few GCs --->

 

[11168:000002432B8735C0]   406231 ms: Scavenge 1965.8 (2298.2) -> 1964.9 (2298.2) MB, 13.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.553, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

 

==== JS stack trace =========================================

 

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF6A620B96D]
Security context: 0x015f508808d1 <JSObject>
    1: keys [0000015F508815B1](this=0x015f50880969 <JSFunction Object (sfi = 000001FCAF28A5A1)>,0x01424a99e649 <Object map = 000000E20EB43C79>)
    2: testFile [000003516B3E7039] [D:\\node_modules\karma-sonarqube-reporter\lib\path-finder.js:45] [bytecode=00000075011398D1 offset=33](this...

 

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Below are the packages I am using.

```
    "@angular/compiler": "13.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.18",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-sonarqube-reporter": "1.4.0",
    "karma-parallel": "0.3.1",
```

Can someone please guide or provide any direction on how to resolve this?

Comment: I would try running the tests without `karma-parallel` to see if the issue is still present. I would also try turning `sourceMaps` off: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3267#issuecomment-467092823.

Comment: tried... doesn't help

Comment: Does it happen both locally and in CI? Can you see if it happens on your colleague's computers and your computer as well? If it happens locally, see what CPU and RAM they have. If it doesn't happen locally but happens on CI, then I would try increasing the CPU and RAM of the CI computers.

Comment: yes, it happens on both CI and local. The `JS stack tract and GC` issue can be avoided based on memory allocation, but Chrome disconnection after all test execution issue stays there...